# Requisição com Axios as vezes funciona e depois para

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, node.js, axios

Estou tentando puxar informações de uma API em NodeJS para um formulário em React através do Axios, acontece que no console ao testar o formulário me retorna o erro:

> "AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name:
> 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request:
> XMLHttpRequest, …} "

Porém as vezes eu reinicio o PC, volto e me retorna com um status 200 OK, e logo em seguida ao tentar mais algumas vezes retorna o erro anterior.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './contact.css';
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import EmailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Email';

const Contact = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3039/contact', {
        name,
        email,
        phoneNumber,
        message,
      });
      console.log(res);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  return ( 
    <div>
      <Form id='form' onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
        <div className="contactContainer">
          <h2>Tem alguma dúvida??<i><EmailIcon /></i></h2>
          <p>Entre em contato e uma resposta em até 48 horas!</p>
        </div>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail" id='formtext'>
          <Form.Label>Nome completo</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Seu nome completo" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail" id='formtext'>
          <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Seu endereço de e-mail" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword"  id='formtext'>
          <Form.Label>Número de telefone</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Seu número de telefone" onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber(e.target.value)} />
        </Form.Group>
        <div className="col-md-12"  id='formtext'>
          <label className="form-a" id='formConfig'>Sua dúvida ou comentário</label>
          <hr />
          <textarea id='formConfig' className="form-control" id='comments' rows='3' placeholder="Digite sua mensagem aqui" onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)} ></textarea>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div className="contactbtn">
          <Button variant="primary" type="submit" id='contactbtn'>
            Enviar
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Contact
```

Answer (score 1):

Suponho que seja algum problema no seu servidor. Tenta investigar o que acontece no back-end ao dar esse erro.
Pontue alguns pontos no seu **back-end** como:

- O que você recebe no body, na sua rota `/contact`
- Como você trata os dados
- Existe tratativa de erro pra dados duplicados?
- Quais são os retornos possíveis (200, 400, 401)?
- Tente simular o erro usando alguma API client (Insomnia ou Postman)

Tudo isso a fim de você saber o motivo do código quebrar.

Comment: Já havia testado a API no Postman e continua funcionando normalmente. Eu tentei agora fazer deploy da API no Heroku para tentar roda direto da API da nuvem ao invés do localhost, e por algum motivo reparei que ao fazer deploy da API ela não funciona enquanto está na nuvem também... Mesmo eu fazendo tudo certo como sempre fiz, com o "Procfile" em "web node server.js", quando tento fazer uma requisição em POST pelo Postman não funciona, mas em localhost sim.

Comment: Eu até mesmo coloquei um get na página inicial da API para saber que ela está rodando, e de fato aparece meu get na página no heroku mas quando tento fazer uma requisição em post no postman acaba me retornando erro também

Comment: Consegue mandar o erro completo do axios aqui?

Comment: Então cara, eu removi o '"env" da pasta gitignore e fiz deploy da API e consumi direto da API ao invés de fazer o teste do Localhost. Enfim, dessa vez funcionou e resolvi meu problema. Muito obrigado por se disponibilizar para ajudar. Tmj